# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' in Formula field

Tags: formula

```
IF(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) <= 19:00:00.000, 'TODAY', 'TOMORROW')
```

I am getting following error for the above formula. What could be possible cause?

Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5

[image]

You'll need to enclose the text in TIMEVALUE() to compare with a timevalue. Right now it acts as if 19:00:00.000 is text.

```
IF(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) <= TIMEVALUE('19:00:00.000'), 'TODAY', 'TOMORROW')
```